# How to fix "sulogin: cannot read /dev/tty7: Operation not permitted" on boot - 17.10 external drive

Tags: boot, partitioning

I recently installed Lubuntu 17.10 on a brand new external hard drive and it's regularly giving me problems during startup. I receive the title message.

If I boot into recovery mode, aside from the video drivers not being loaded, everything seems fine.

I've loaded a live CD and ran the "Check Disk" option. That will correct the issue temporarily, but one or two boots later, the problem invariably starts again.

When installing the OS, this is how I formatted the drive, borrowing from recommendations I found on the web: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSTcF.jpg

I've reformatted the drive and started from scratch twice now and, in case it's something worth mentioning, I noticed this last time that it worked for several days and multiple boots, but right after I installed postgresql 9.6 and setup a couple servers, that's when the boot problems started showing up. It may be nothing more than a coincidence...

Any pointers? Things I can try to troubleshoot? I've read others talk about editing the /etc/fstab, but I'm still relatively new to Linux as an OS and I don't know what I'm looking for there.

UPDATE: [Other error messages are beginning to pop up off and on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roObC.jpg). Including these outputs from "journalctl -xb":

- Cannot find TOCBLOCK, database may be corrupt
- No caching mode page found
- SystemID range  conflicts with Opregion
- fsck failed with error code 4
- Dependency failed for local File System

Just thinking out loud here, but could it have anything to do with the fact that I'm plugging the drive into multiple computers? I need it to be stable for my laptop though while I travel, that's the whole reason I opted for an external drive in the first place.

***Thank you in advance for any help you can offer! Let me know if you'd like for me to post any more information!***

Comment: I am taking a stab in the dark here, but do you have Fast Boot disabled in your Windows?  You might be getting that if it cannot mount the Windows partition if you have it set for auto mounting.  That can be caused by hibernation data on the drive when Fast Booting in enabled in Windows.

Comment: @Terrance Interesting! So I gave that a shot and rebooted, only to see a different error message displayed talking about a firmware bug TSC_DEADLINE, prompting to upgrade microcode. So I went into recovery mode, installed the "intel-microcode" package, and I've now had four reboots without any issues! *knock on wood* I'll give it a few more restarts to see if it holds. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could be of some assistance and that it is working.  =)

Comment: Cropping up again, off and on. Updating original thread with new error messages.

Comment: I could see changing systems possibly causing issues like that because of when you install Linux on a system it installs drivers for that system.  You might be better trying a [Live with Persistence](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/).

Comment: Ahh interesting! So if plugged the drive into my desktop  (Intel, nVIDIA) to initially set up the drive and install the OS, whenever I take the drive to my laptop (AMD, on-board Radeon), that may be what's throwing it for a loop?

Comment: Is there any way I could have it setup for both environments?

Comment: I know a Live system can do it, but I am not aware of how to do it for multiple video cards on an installed system.  I haven't had a need for that myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE 20180327: I recently came across a fairly esoteric command that, for the past two weeks, has fixed my startup issues. Here's what I did...

Hold down ALT+SysRq (on my laptop, SysRq is a function key on HOME, requiring me to also hold down the FN key) then, while still holding those keys down, SLOWLY -- wait a second or two between each key -- type out (in lowercase):

`r e i s u o`

This will do a number of things, including shutdown the computer. And voila! I've been trouble free for the past two weeks.

So what exactly does that do?

- R: Switch keyboard from raw mode to XLATE mode
- E: Send the SIGTERM signal to all processes except init
- I: Send the SIGKILL signal to all processes except init
- S: Sync all mounted filesystems
- U: Remount all mounted filesystems in read-only mode
- O: Immediately shutdown the system without unmounting partitions or syncing. If you instead want to reboot the computer, type B instead.

---

UPDATE 20171120: It seems there is a recurring issue with /dev/sdb3, wherein inodes get orphaned. Whenever the system boots in Maintenance Mode, running the following has consistently corrected the issue:

```
$ umount /dev/sdb3 # as a precaution, sdb3 is usually not mounted yet
$ fsck -y /dev/sdb3
```

This normally returns a notice saying that "Free blocks count wrong..." then "Free inodes count wrong..." followed by a fix.

Why the system regularly fubars this up, the jury is still out. But in the meantime, this fixes the system and brings everything back in working order.

---

UPDATE 20171113: Welp... Turns out this answer was a temporary stopgap measure at best... The system will boot up multiple times in a row with no problem. But then, seemingly out of nowhere, it will start booting into maintenance mode. The only "fix" then, is to boot into recovery mode and run a check disk. And if that doesn't fix the default boot, then to load a live CD and run the full fsck checkup on it.

---

The fact that the system worked just fine in recovery mode made me confident the disk was not corrupted. Also, since video drivers are not fully loaded in recovery mode, it made me suspect it had something to do with my laptop's onboard AMD Radeon chip.

This lead me to eventually discovering the following command:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
```

This command lists available packages that correspond to the system's hardware. In my case, this listed "amd64-microcode". After installing that package, I have not ran into any more boot issues (knock on wood). I repeated the same process when the drive is connected to my main desktop so the drive should be fully ready to go in both environments.